# Is there a way to unify curl, gradient, and divergence operators as special cases of a more general operator?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I realize there's probably an answer to this question somewhere on this site, but it would seem I'm having trouble picking the right search terms.

In my multivariable calculus class, the professor just spent some time going over the relationships between the integral theorems of calculus by essentially saying that they all are examples of how integrating some function over the boundary of a domain (path, surface, solid) is the same as integrating some form of its "derivative" over the interior of that domain. The issue is, while the boundary operator seems to be consistent across all of the integral theorems presented (line integral theorem, Stokes' theorem, and Gauss' theorem), the notion of the derivative is different in each one: for Stokes', it's the curl; for Gauss', it's the divergence; and for the line integral theorem, it's the gradient.

I was wondering: is there any natural way of generalizing the curl, divergence, and gradient operators, so that they become special cases of some more broad notion of "taking the derivative"? Or perhaps to other dimensions? (Or is there something special about $\mathbb R^{3}$ that makes it unique for vector calculus?)

(Sorry if this question is too open-ended or ill-defined for this site; regardless, if anybody has any suggestions on topics to study or other resources to consult, I would very much appreciate those as well.)

Comment: Of course. They are special cases of the exterior derivative with differential forms, and this generalizes to higher dimensions. You might find some of my lectures on YouTube (linked in my profile) of interest.

Comment: excellent question. the natural setting to talk about these theorems is in differential geometry with the (generalized) Stokes theorem. The derivative operator is called the exterior derivative, and Stokes theorem looks the same in all dimensions. These three theorems are then special cases of a more general theorem.

Comment: Of course, to understand the exterior derivative you have to understand tensor products...my bane of first year grad school!

Comment: If you prefer textbook sources, I really like "The Geometry of Physics: An Introduction" by Frankel. It goes through differential geometry, tensor analysis, and exterior calculus in a beautiful way.

Comment: @Alan You very much do *not* need to learn tensor products to learn differential forms. All you need is determinants, which OP certainly knows.

Answer (score 1):

To go off of the comment by @Ted Shifrin, they are special cases of the exterior derivative "$d$", and the hodge star operator "$*$".

See:

Exterior Derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative

Hodge Star https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator

For example, on a differential 1-form (in 3-dimensions) $\omega$, the divergence is$\ * d *\omega$. The curl is given by$\ *d\omega$. The gradient of some function $f$ is $df$. To make all of these resulting 1-forms into vectors like we work with in calculus 3, we can $\sharp$ (use the metric tensor (also needed for the hodge star operation)) these 1-forms which turns them into vectors.

I also find the comment by @peek-a-boo on (generalized) Stokes theorem incredibly useful as well.

See: Generalized Stokes' Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem

The generalized Stokes' theorem combines both Gauss's theorem and Stokes's theorem for n-dimensional objects and relates them to n-1 dimensional objects. Even the fundamental theorem of calculus is part of generalized Stokes' theorem, as it relates the endpoints in the integral to the curve, relating a 1-dimensional object to 0-dimensional objects.

Hope this helps, it is an excellent question! As an aside, I learned about a lot of this through the *DifferentialGeometry* Maple package (there is a generalized one from USU). Chern also worked considerably with differential forms. They are an amazing tool.